# Script to start my VPN if I'm connected to a specific Network / SSID [El Capitan update]

Tags: wifi, applescript, macos, vpn

I'm searching an AppleScript to automatically start my University VPN if I'm connected to the University network.
I already found some solutions for older OS X Versions, but they're not working anymore on El Capitan.

Edit: An existing [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199528/how-to-automatically-connect-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-network) does not work on El Capitan, I'm getting this error:

> Can’t get current configuration of service
>   id "B7124700-2559-4F93-BC2A-205723054B5B" of network preferences. 
>   System Events got an error: Can’t get current configuration of service id "B7124700-2559-4F93-BC2A-205723054B5B" of network preferences. (-1728)

Comment: You might look at [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/), which allows all sorts of context sensitive actions, including things like joining specific networks.

Comment: Also there are several VPN clients that can do that for you based on different criteria e.g. Shimo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically connect VPN when connecting to a network?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199528/how-to-automatically-connect-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-network)

Comment: @agentroadkill Exactly the same request, but the solution mentioned in that thread doesn't work for me in El Capitan. Always the same error: System Events got an error: Can’t get current configuration of service id "B71...."....

Comment: Ah! My mistake. Could you post the full error message in your original question so the answer can be updated?

Comment: @agentroadkill No problem, done!

Comment: @blm ControlPlane does not have the function to start / stop VPN. But thank you anyways!!

Comment: Interesting, older versions do allow controlling the VPN, I used that on Snow Leopard all the time, but it looks like it's been removed. Sorry, should have looked at the latest version before suggesting it.