# type of emails from Contacts.app in AppleScript (on El Capitan)

Tags: email, applescript, contacts, macos

I want to work with a list of all email addresses that appear in my address book. I thought I could simply `set` such a list with AppleScript, and use the elements, maybe after casting the references to strings, as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122631/34698) answer suggests. However, the code below runs into a casting error, with or without explicit casting (e.g. `as string`):

> error "Can’t make «class az21» 1 of «class azf4» id
>   \"C74972A5-88D4-4B0F-8DEA-304914926EE6:ABPerson\" of application
>   \"Contacts\" into the expected type." number -1700 from «class az21» 1
>   of «class azf4» id "C74972A5-88D4-4B0F-8DEA-304914926EE6:ABPerson"

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set allEmails to every email of every person
end tell
repeat with anEmail in allEmails
    display dialog anEmail
end repeat
```

This problem, of course, also inhibits any more meaningful uses of the email addresses.

What is this about, and what is a workable way to collect and access all email addresses in my address book?

I am running Public Beta 5 of El Capitan, though I did not test whether the behavior is any different on older (= actual) releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**allEmails** is a list that contains several lists, each sublist contains emails of a contact.

`email` is an object, you need to get the `value` of this object.

So, you need a loop for each list, and another loop for each value.

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set myList to value of emails of people
end tell
repeat with aList in myList
    repeat with anEmail in aList
        display dialog anEmail
    end repeat
end repeat
```